# Find Nested self referred records in same table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem to find nested self referred records from DB. How can retrieve all the nested self referred records from mysql database..

consider example below

```
ID RefID Name Value
1   NA    A    10
2   NA    B    20
3   1     C    30 (it refering ID 1)
4   1     D    40 (it refering ID 1)
5   2     E    50 (it refering ID 2)
6   3     F    60 (it refering ID 3)
7   6     G    70 (it refering ID 6)

input --> ID=1

output ---> ID= 3,4,6,7


                ID -> 1
                      |-> ID 3, 4
                             |-> ID 6
                                     |-> ID 7

like that i want to find all sub levels....
```

Now i want to find self referred nested sub records from DB...

If i want to find ID=1 means it should display all the sub records of it. i.e wherever RefID = 1 and its referred ID have any RefID means that also come to display

How can i retrieve the data from DB..

Is it any SQL Query can able to retrieve the records from DB

Comment: Which rows you expected in your result from your example?

Comment: It's still unclear what you asking: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE RefID = 1`?

Comment: As you've probably realised, MySQL has no native support for recursion. So, choices include: using a sproc; joining the table to itself as often as could be required; handling the logic at the application level (e.g. a PHP loop); or switching to another data model (e.g. nested set).

Comment: not clear,  you have to make clear output of your required answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support recursive queries.

You could either create a function that creates the recursion for you within mysql, or let your client code handle this issue by looping and re-query the database for as deep needed.